# registering a rest API with OAuth

Tags: rest, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have written a web application which makes REST API calls to a message broker. The message broker contains already written REST APIs to which can be used to get message broker data. The message broker is written in a way in which each REST API call sends the user name and password which is encoded with base64. I need to make a login to my web app and authenticate it with OAuth.Does anyone know how to do this? How to authenticate the REST APIs with OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Add OAuth 2.0 to your web server. This is very standard with lots of libraries available. You did not specify the Identity Provider that you will use (Google, Facebook, Auth0, Okta, etc), but each vendor has documents and libraries for you to use in your desired language.

Step 2: Add an Authorization Header to your API calls. The standard method is to add the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer access_token` when making an API call.

Step 3: Add OAuth token verification to your API. When your API receives a request, it extracts the Authorization header and verifies the Bearer token. How this is done depends on the Identity Provider. For example, some vendors provide a Signed JWT (which you verify with the vendors public certificate), others provide an opaque access token (which you verify by calling the vendor's token endpoint). Add internal caching of tokens so that you don't need to verify on every API call.

If you understand OAuth 2.0 the above steps are straightforward to implement. If you don't Oracle has a set of videos which are excellent for getting started understanding OAuth.

[Oracle Cloud Primers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKCk3OyNwIzuD_jxWu-JddooM2yjX5q99)

If your desired OAuth implementation does not require users logging in and is a server to server service that you control on both ends, then you can use just part of OAuth which is Signed JWT (JWS). You create a Json data structure with your desired content and sign it with a private key. This creates a token that you can use in the above steps. You would then validate the token using your public key. You can use self-generated keypairs generated by OpenSSL or similar products for your signing and verification.